# playa refering to another playa

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

Ok, let's see if I can explain this question, I have a channel with a playa field which refers to channel which has other playa fields in it that I want to display on the given page. How do call the other playa field? on that playa selections channel since just calling them doesn't work of course.

I get about this far, but don't know the next step?

```
{exp:playa:children field="FROM CHANNEL A"}
    {title}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

**EDIT**

Hi Lisa, Thanks for responding I am somewhat new to playa and even to EE itself lets see if I can explain this better.

I have a channel called "data_entry" with a playa list `{location_source}` the items on the list refer to another channel called "locations" which contains another playa field called `{second_order_location}` that I want to display right before the `{title}` of the first playa list. Does that make sense?

```
{exp:playa:children field="location_source"}
    {if first_order_location_parent}{first_order_location},{/if} 
    {title}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

**EDIT**
I wrote

```
     {exp:playa:children channel="data_entry" var_prefix="data_entry"}
        {data_entry:exp:playa:children channel="nwt_locations" var_prefix="first_order_location_parent"}
            {data_entry:title} - {first_order_location_parent:title}
        {/data_entry:exp:playa:children} 
      {/exp:playa:children}
```

All I get is the same as if I wrote {title} am I missing something? I am not sure what to do about the parameters. Thanks So much for time

Comment: What version of Playa are you on?  And is this inside a channel entries tag?  I'd love to know if this is isolated in a template, or part of a larger template.  Definitely worth reducing as part of troubleshooting.

Comment: It is inside a channel entry and Playa version 4.3.3, EE 2.5.5

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer based on the OP edited answer :)

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
    <h3>Article Media</h3>
    <ul>
        {exp:playa:children channel="news" var_prefix="news"}
            {news:exp:playa:children channel="editors" var_prefix="editor"}
                {news:title} - {editor:title}
            {/news:exp:playa:children}
    {/exp:playa:children}
    </ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is directly from the example for var_prefix here:

http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/children.html

You'll need to update your channel= parameters, and if you want to change the var prefixes, make sure you change them wherever they're referenced.  Does that help?

-Lisa, P&T

Comment: Hi Lisa, thanks for responding I am somewhat new to playa nad even EE itslf lets see if i can explain this better.

Comment: Check out my revised answer. :)